# The name 'stringInfo' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string stringConnectionString = null;
        SqlConnection objSqlConnection;
        SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();         
        string stringCommandText = string.Empty;         


        stringConnectionString = ("Data Source=192.161.0.0;Initial Catalog=kkh_final;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=yyyyyyy");
        objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(stringConnectionString);
        objSqlConnection.Open();
        objSqlCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;
        objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objSqlCommand.CommandText = "PCL0105A0_MR_Patients";
    }

    public void clsPatients(DataRow objDataRow, string[] stringInfo, string stringCommandText)
    {

        SqlParameter[] objSqlParameter;
        stringCommandText = "PCL0105A0_MR_Patients";
        int intRowIndex;
        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter objSqlDataAdapter;                                 

        try
        {
            objSqlParameter = new SqlParameter[63];   

            objSqlParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@p_BO_ID", "KKHG");
            objSqlParameter[0].Value = stringInfo[0];

            objSqlParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@p_HRN_ID", "A00025");
            objSqlParameter[1].Value = objDataRow["HRN_ID"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@p_Short_Name", "Gowtham");
            objSqlParameter[2].Value = objDataRow["Short_Name"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@p_Gender", "Male");
            objSqlParameter[3].Value = objDataRow["Gender"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[4] = new SqlParameter("@p_DOB", "05/06/1992");
            objSqlParameter[4].Value = objDataRow["DOB"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[5] = new SqlParameter("@p_Street_Name1", "Moovendar Nagar");
            objSqlParameter[5].Value = objDataRow["Street_Name1"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[6] = new SqlParameter("@p_Ph_No1", "9585188641");
            objSqlParameter[6].Value = objDataRow["Ph_No1"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[7] = new SqlParameter("@p_VIP_Status", "Yes");
            objSqlParameter[7].Value = objDataRow["VIP_Status"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[8] = new SqlParameter("@p_Death_Status", "Will");
            objSqlParameter[8].Value = objDataRow["Death_Status"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[9] = new SqlParameter("@p_Trans_Status", "test");
            objSqlParameter[9].Value = objDataRow["Trans_Status"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[10] = new SqlParameter("@p_Citizenship", "Indian");
            objSqlParameter[10].Value = objDataRow["Citizenship"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[11] = new SqlParameter("@p_Adm_Date", "05/06/1992");
            objSqlParameter[11].Value = objDataRow["Adm_Date"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[12] = new SqlParameter("@p_Ref_Case", "NA");
            objSqlParameter[12].Value = objDataRow["Ref_Case"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[13] = new SqlParameter("@p_Blk", "");
            objSqlParameter[13].Value = objDataRow["Blk"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[14] = new SqlParameter("@p_Level_No", "25");
            objSqlParameter[14].Value = objDataRow["Level_No"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[15] = new SqlParameter("@p_Unit_No", "25");
            objSqlParameter[15].Value = objDataRow["Unit_No"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[16] = new SqlParameter("@p_Street_Name2", "Geetha Nagar");
            objSqlParameter[16].Value = objDataRow["Street_Name2"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[17] = new SqlParameter("@p_City", "Thanjavoor City");
            objSqlParameter[17].Value = objDataRow["City"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[18] = new SqlParameter("@p_Geographical_Area", "Thanjavoor");
            objSqlParameter[18].Value = objDataRow["Geographical_Area"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[19] = new SqlParameter("@p_District", "Thanjavoor");
            objSqlParameter[19].Value = objDataRow["District"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[20] = new SqlParameter("@p_Country", "India");
            objSqlParameter[20].Value = objDataRow["Country"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[21] = new SqlParameter("@p_Post_Code", "636111");
            objSqlParameter[21].Value = objDataRow["Post_Code"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[22] = new SqlParameter("@p_Ph_No2", "8792188641");
            objSqlParameter[22].Value = objDataRow["Ph_No2"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[23] = new SqlParameter("@p_Ph_No3", "9626222891");
            objSqlParameter[23].Value = objDataRow["Ph_No3"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[24] = new SqlParameter("@p_Ph_No4", "");
            objSqlParameter[24].Value = objDataRow["Ph_No4"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[25] = new SqlParameter("@p_Ph_No5", "");
            objSqlParameter[25].Value = objDataRow["Ph_No5"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[26] = new SqlParameter("@p_Ph_No6", "");
            objSqlParameter[26].Value = objDataRow["Ph_No6"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[27] = new SqlParameter("@p_Email", "gtusk55@gmail.com");
            objSqlParameter[27].Value = objDataRow["Email"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[28] = new SqlParameter("@p_Death_Date", "05/06/2085");
            objSqlParameter[28].Value = objDataRow["Death_Date"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[29] = new SqlParameter("@p_Discharge_Disposition", "");
            objSqlParameter[29].Value = objDataRow["Discharge_Disposition"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[30] = new SqlParameter("@p_Long_Name", "");
            objSqlParameter[30].Value = objDataRow["Long_Name"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[31] = new SqlParameter("@p_Remarks", "");
            objSqlParameter[31].Value = objDataRow["Remarks"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[47] = new SqlParameter("@p_delmark", "");
            objSqlParameter[47].Value = objDataRow["delmark"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[48] = new SqlParameter("@p_gw_status", "");
            objSqlParameter[48].Value = objDataRow["gw_status"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[49] = new SqlParameter("@p_data_source", "");
            objSqlParameter[49].Value = objDataRow["data_source"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[50] = new SqlParameter("@p_Created_At", "");
            objSqlParameter[50].Value = objDataRow["data_source"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[51] = new SqlParameter("@p_Created_By", "");
            objSqlParameter[51].Value = objDataRow["data_source"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[52] = new SqlParameter("@p_Created_On", "");
            objSqlParameter[52].Value = objDataRow["data_source"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[53] = new SqlParameter("@p_Modified_At", "");
            objSqlParameter[53].Value = objDataRow["data_source"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[54] = new SqlParameter("@p_Modified_By", "");
            objSqlParameter[54].Value = objDataRow["data_source"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[55] = new SqlParameter("@p_Modified_On", "");
            objSqlParameter[55].Value = objDataRow["data_source"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[56] = new SqlParameter("@p_Temp_ID", "");
            objSqlParameter[56].Value = objDataRow["Temp_ID"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[57] = new SqlParameter("@p_Temp_Flg", "");
            objSqlParameter[57].Value = objDataRow["Temp_Flg"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[58] = new SqlParameter("@p_Latest_HRN", "");
            objSqlParameter[58].Value = objDataRow["Latest_HRN"].ToString();

            objSqlParameter[59] = new SqlParameter("@p_Latest_HRN", "");
            objSqlParameter[59].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            // objSqlParameter[60] = new SqlParameter("@p_error_code", "");
            //objSqlParameter[60].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            objSqlParameter[60] = new SqlParameter("@p_error_msg", "");
            objSqlParameter[60].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            objSqlParameter[61] = new SqlParameter("@p_result", "");
            objSqlParameter[61].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            objSqlParameter[62] = new SqlParameter("@p_data_source", "");
            objSqlParameter[62].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            objSqlParameter[63] = new SqlParameter("@p_dml_indicator", "");
            objSqlParameter[63].Value = objDataRow["dml_indicator"].ToString();

             objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(objSqlParameter);

            objSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objSqlCommand);
            objSqlDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);

            for (intRowIndex = 0; intRowIndex < objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; intRowIndex++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[intRowIndex][0].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Here this is my code, and tried lot, if i solve one error, another one will occur, here what is the problem to my code? i am going correct or not?

friends am new to this code field, so help me

thanks in advance friends

Comment: Im seriously **not** going to search for `stringInfo`. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This line _objSqlConnection.Open(stringInfo, stringCommandText);_ should be _objSqlConnection.Open();_ Then where have you defined that string and what is its purpose is too vague to say

Comment: steve i tried , if i press debug no response

Comment: Easiest error to solve

Comment: Where exactly are you calling clsPatients? You create your connection, try and open it (incorrectly using 'stringInfo', which hasn't been created and stringCommandText, which is blank), but never call clsPatients.

Comment: yes i want to create connection , clspatients is my CS source file

Comment: Did my answer below help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's an example of how to create a connection, call a stored procedure and fill a dataset, which ultimately is what I think you're trying to achieve. You'll obviously need to tweak it for your data but hopefully this will get you on your way:

```
stringConnectionString = ("Data Source=192.161.0.0;Initial Catalog=kkh_final;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=yyyyyyy");
DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(stringConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProcedure", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter pdParam = new SqlParameter("@YourParam", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    pdParam.Value = pd;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pdParam);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    try
    {
        da.Fill(objDataSet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        string error = ex.Message;
    }
}
```